# No DNS domain configured for <myServer> whilst joining AD domain

Tags: networking, server, samba, dns

So I'm having the lovely experience of attempting to join an Ubuntu-Server instance to a corporate AD domain built exclusively for Windows.

I've configgured SSHD and SAMBA however, when I run:

```
sudo net ads join -U <myUserName>%<myPassword>
```

I get the following results:

> Joined '<myServer>' to dns domain '<myDoman>' No DNS
>   domain configured for <myServer>. Unable to perform DNS Update. DNS
>   update failed: NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER

I've added the following to my `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

> auto ens32
>
> iface ens32 inet dhcp
>
> dns-nameservers <myDNS>

Where `ens32` is my primary network interface.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add the search domain in the /etc/network/interfaces file

```
dns_search <myDomain>
```

Comment: I tried this and go the same error, however, after rebooting (to try again) I now can't log in at all

Comment: As a local user that is, without loggin in as a domain user first